# How to insert a selected sum and other information to a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to add a new project bill to a bill-table that has

1. the sum of all work hours multiplied by hourly wage multiplied by the discount
   and
2. sum of all equipment selling prices multiplied by their discounts multiplied by their quantity
   and
3. List item

   also project's primary key.

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE labourtype (
lkey SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
ltype VARCHAR(20),
hourwage DECIMAL);


CREATE TABLE project (
pkey SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
ptype VARCHAR(20),
p_finished DATE,
has_been_paid INT DEFAULT 0);


CREATE TABLE equipment (
ekey SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
ename VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
purchase_price DECIMAL NOT NULL,
in_stock INT DEFAULT 0);


CREATE TABLE labour_in_project (
lkey INT NOT NULL,
pkey INT NOT NULL,

workday DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
workhours INT,
discount DECIMAL,

PRIMARY KEY(lkey, pkey, workday),
FOREIGN KEY (lkey) REFERENCES labourtype(lkey),
FOREIGN KEY (pkey) REFERENCES project(pkey));


CREATE TABLE equipments_used(
pkey INT NOT NULL,
ekey INT NOT NULL,
sold DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,

quantity int,
selling_price DECIMAL,
discount DECIMAL,

PRIMARY KEY(pkey, ekey, sold),
FOREIGN KEY (pkey) REFERENCES project(pkey),
FOREIGN KEY (ekey) REFERENCES equipment(ekey));


CREATE TABLE bill (
bkey SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
pkey INT NOT NULL,
labour_price DECIMAL,
equipment_price DECIMAL,
FOREIGN KEY (pkey) REFERENCES project(pkey));
```

Here is the selection of total costs of our workers hard, painstaking labour:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS workprice
FROM (SELECT labourtype.hourwage * lip.discount * lip.workhours as price
FROM labourtype INNER JOIN labour_in_project AS lip
    ON labourtype.lkey = lip.lkey AND pkey = 1) AS priceoflabour;
```

And here is the selection of our equipment costs:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS equipmentprice
FROM (SELECT eu.quantity * eu.selling_price * eu.discount as price
    FROM equipments_used AS eu
    WHERE eu.pkey = 1) AS equipment_costs;
```

Now all I would need to do is to insert workprice, equipmentprice and pkey 1 to a bill table. How to do this?

Comment: Did you try my answer and did it work as expected?

Comment: Yup, I think it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that only for pkey 1, the solution is quite obvious:

```
INSERT INTO
    bill (pkey, labour_price, equipmentprice)
VALUES
(1,
 (SELECT
      SUM(llp.price)
  FROM
      (SELECT
               labourtype.hourwage * lip.discount * lip.workhours AS price
       FROM
           labourtype
               INNER JOIN labour_in_project AS lip
                          ON labourtype.lkey = lip.lkey AND pkey = 1) AS llp),
 (SELECT
      SUM(ep.price)
  FROM
      (SELECT
               eu.quantity * eu.selling_price * eu.discount AS price
       FROM
           equipments_used AS eu
       WHERE eu.pkey = 1) AS ep));
```

You can write a function that takes `pkey` as an argument, and does the above insert for the given `pkey`.

You could also do that for all `pkey`s with INSERT INTO SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO
    bill (pkey, labour_price, equipment_price)
SELECT
    p.pkey                                                                            AS pkey,
    (SELECT
         SUM(llp.price)
     FROM
         (SELECT
              labourtype.hourwage * lip.discount * lip.workhours AS price
          FROM
              labourtype
                  INNER JOIN labour_in_project AS lip
                             ON labourtype.lkey = lip.lkey AND pkey = p.pkey) AS llp) AS workprice,
    (SELECT
         SUM(ep.price)
     FROM
         (SELECT
              eu.quantity * eu.selling_price * eu.discount AS price
          FROM
              equipments_used AS eu
          WHERE eu.pkey = p.pkey) AS ep)                                              AS equipmentprice
FROM
    project p;
```